# Find negative amts (column D), add the sum grouped by Column J neg total divided by the # of neg # per MID, add to the positive MID amt (column D)

Tags: excel, vba, formula

There is VBA code that creates this spreadsheet.  My only problem now is removing all negative numbers in column D.  The MID (column J) totals must match to a larger project.  Therefore, I can't just delete the negative amounts in column D.  If there is a matching MID that also has a matching Trans Ref (Column B), I'd like to sum the negative amounts in column D for each MID and then divide the amount by the number of negative numbers for each MID and then add the divided amount to each matching Trans Ref positive amount.

[image]

If there is a matching MID and no matching Trans Ref then I need to total the sum of the negative amounts for each MID and then divide the amount by the number of negative numbers for each MID and then add that amount into each MID positive number.   Can anyone assist me with this project?  I've tried many different formulas to try to COUNTIF negative, but I'm not getting what I really need.   This will eventually be added into the overall VBA code, but I can do it will just formulas as well.  I can work with either.  Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: try : select cell `A1` > data > filter. | then filter the table according to your needed options.